# Retrieving multiple attributes with jQuery Sortable

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

As far as I know, jQuery UI Sortable only reads a single specified attribute to serialize or generate an output array, but want I really want is to retrieve multiple attributes and join them into a single output string (either serialized or to an array).

Here's my HTML example:

```html
<ul id="sort">
<li data-color="red" data-size="small">apple</li>
<li data-color="yellow" data-size="medium">banana</li>
<li data-color="green" data-size="big">watermelon</li>
</ul>
```

I need to output the values of the two data-attributes. How can I do this?

I tried to do something like this:

```js
$(function() {
$('#sort').sortable().disableSelection();
$("#sort").on( "sortupdate", function( event, ui ) {
    var output = $(this).sortable("toArray", {
        attribute: {"data-color", "data-size"}
    });
    //do something
} );
});
```

But it doesn't work, I guess because the `attribute` does not support an array as its value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about a [`map()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.map/) to place the values in an array:

```
$("#sort").on( "sortupdate", function( event, ui ) {
    dataArray = $.map($(this).children('li'), function(el){
        return {'color':$(el).data('color'), 'size':$(el).data('size')}; 
    });
});
```

[<kbd>JSFiddle</kbd>](http://jsfiddle.net/rm9Pn/3)